# Is there any way to write $1/a + 1/b = 1/c$ in linear form?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{c}$ can be simplified as
$\frac{ab}{a+b}=c$ which is still nonlinear. Is there any way to write it in a linear form?

Comment: Nope, you can't.

Comment: What do you mean "writing an equation in linear form?" Are you asking whether the given equation is linear in a, b, and c? Also, how does that equation simplify to the expression $\frac{ab}{a+b}$?

Answer (score 1):

No, but it is naturally the null set of a quadratic form. 
$$ bc+ca - ab = 0 $$
Indeed, the form is $SL_3 \mathbb Z$ equivalent to $y^2 - zx,$ which is why we get a very nice parametrization of solutions.

For coprime integers $u,v$ take
$$ a = u^2 + uv, $$
$$ b = uv + v^2, $$
$$ c = uv, $$
to get integer solutions. To get $a,b,c$ nonzero as in the original formulation, take both $u,v$ nonzero as well.

```
    a        b        c
    2        2        1     u,v:        1        1
    6        3        2     u,v:        2        1
   12        4        3     u,v:        3        1
   15       10        6     u,v:        3        2
   20        5        4     u,v:        4        1
   28       21       12     u,v:        4        3
   30        6        5     u,v:        5        1
   35       14       10     u,v:        5        2
   40       24       15     u,v:        5        3
   42        7        6     u,v:        6        1
   45       36       20     u,v:        5        4
   56        8        7     u,v:        7        1
   63       18       14     u,v:        7        2
   66       55       30     u,v:        6        5
   70       30       21     u,v:        7        3
   72        9        8     u,v:        8        1
   77       44       28     u,v:        7        4
   84       60       35     u,v:        7        5
   88       33       24     u,v:        8        3
   90       10        9     u,v:        9        1
   91       78       42     u,v:        7        6
   99       22       18     u,v:        9        2
  104       65       40     u,v:        8        5
  110       11       10     u,v:       10        1
  117       52       36     u,v:        9        4
  120      105       56     u,v:        8        7
  126       70       45     u,v:        9        5
  130       39       30     u,v:       10        3
  132       12       11     u,v:       11        1
  143       26       22     u,v:       11        2
  144      112       63     u,v:        9        7
  153      136       72     u,v:        9        8
  154       42       33     u,v:       11        3
  156       13       12     u,v:       12        1
  165       60       44     u,v:       11        4
  170      119       70     u,v:       10        7
  176       80       55     u,v:       11        5
  182       14       13     u,v:       13        1
  187      102       66     u,v:       11        6
  190      171       90     u,v:       10        9
  195       30       26     u,v:       13        2
  198      126       77     u,v:       11        7
  204       85       60     u,v:       12        5
  208       48       39     u,v:       13        3
  209      152       88     u,v:       11        8
  210       15       14     u,v:       14        1
  220      180       99     u,v:       11        9
  221       68       52     u,v:       13        4
  228      133       84     u,v:       12        7
  231      210      110     u,v:       11       10
  234       90       65     u,v:       13        5
  238       51       42     u,v:       14        3
  240       16       15     u,v:       15        1
  247      114       78     u,v:       13        6
  255       34       30     u,v:       15        2
  260      140       91     u,v:       13        7
  266       95       70     u,v:       14        5
  272       17       16     u,v:       16        1
  273      168      104     u,v:       13        8
  276      253      132     u,v:       12       11
  285       76       60     u,v:       15        4
  286      198      117     u,v:       13        9
  299      230      130     u,v:       13       10
  304       57       48     u,v:       16        3
  306       18       17     u,v:       17        1
  312      264      143     u,v:       13       11
  322      207      126     u,v:       14        9
```